# Python: read output script twice and write two columns to csv

Tags: python, csv, stdout

This is my first python **(2.4)** program and I could use your help.
I have a csv file

```
HOST, PATH
server1, /path/to/file1.py
server2, /path/to/file2.py
server3, /path/to/file3.py
```

That executes a command to each PATH on column 2/row[1]

In the output of the command I search for text and append them to new columns.

Example command output:

```
Command: python /path/to/file1.py
Output: server1 (NTFS) Reply:Yes
```

I would like make my new csv file like:

```
HOST, PATH, PLATFORM, REPLY
server1, /path/to/file1.py, Windows, Yes
server2, /path/to/file2.py, Linux, Yes
server3, /path/to/file3.py, BSD, No
```

I havnt yet got it to work with reading the same output line and appending two columns with different results.  I have tried closing the writer and opening a new one within the same reader with no joy.  I have tried indenting with no luck.  The closest I have gotten is having it accurately search for both strings but it only writes to one column.

I have also tried first searching for the os platform and writing the changes to a new file
Then, opening the new file to write another row

Of course I could force this to work by running the commands again and searching separately, but thats redundant and unnecessary.

```
import datetime
import csv
import os, time
from stat import * # ST_SIZE etc
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

# Set Date
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")

# Files
filename = "my_list.csv"
results = "results/results_" + today + ".csv" # Eg. results_04-14-2012.csv

# Commands
command = "python"
SP = " "

incsv = open(filename, 'rb')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(incsv)

    outcsv = open(results, 'w')
    try:
        writer = csv.writer(outcsv)

        for row in reader:
            p = Popen(command + SP + row[1], shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
            stdout, empty = p.communicate()

            print 'Command: %s\nOutput: %s\n' % (command + SP + row[1], stdout)

            if not stdout:
                writer.writerow(row + ['PLATFORM']) # Create header for new column when first line is empty on stdout
            elif 'BSD' in stdout:
                writer.writerow(row + ['BSD'])
            elif 'Linux' in stdout or 'swap' in stdout or 'LLVM' in stdout or 'EBR' in stdout:
                writer.writerow(row + ['Linux'])
            elif 'NTFS' in stdout:
                writer.writerow(row + ['Windows'])
            else:
                writer.writerow(row + ['Error Scanning'])

                    reply = open(results, 'w')
                    try:
                        writer = csv.writer(platform)

                        for row in reader:

                            if not stdout:
                                writer.writerow(row + ['REPLY']) # Create header for new column when first line is empty on stdout
                            elif 'Reply:Yes' in stdout:
                                writer.writerow(row + ['Yes'])
                            elif 'Reply:No' in stdout :
                                writer.writerow(row + ['No'])

                            else:
                                writer.writerow(row + ['Error'])

                    finally:
                        reply.close()
    finally:
        outcsv.close()
finally:
    incsv.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect all the information you want from the output, and write it out using a single call to `writerow()`. E.g.,

```
newdata = ['BSD', 'Yes']
...
writer.writerow(row + newdata)
```

Of course you will be building up `newdata` in steps, by parsing the script results.

PS. Update your python! 2.4 is way too old. Updating will make your life easier in countless ways.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a production server that I cannot upgrade.  Thanks for your help, I'll see where that gets me.

Comment: I thought it might be an easy fix, and that it was.  Very grateful, thanks alexis

Answer (score 1):

You may not need csv if you have a 1:1 mapping between input lines and output lines. Just process each line and spit out a new one.

**Method 1: Pipes**

```
import sys
import subprocess

def parse_csv(input, output):
    # echo headings with new columns
    print >> output, input.readline() + ', PLATFORM, REPLY'

    for line in input.readlines():
        server, _, path = line.partition(',')
        path = path.strip()
        p = subprocess.Popen(command + ' ' + path,
                             stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             shell=True)
        stdout, _ = p.communicate()

        # your additional logic goes here based on contents of stdout

        # when ready to output, just print, e.g.
        print >> output, '%s, %s, %s' % (line, stdout, 'Yes')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_csv(sys.stdin, sys.stdout)
```

Execute with

```
$ cat servers_and_paths.csv | python add_two_columns.py > servers_paths_and_flags.csv
```

**Method 2: Files**

If you don't want to use pipes, use with clauses to handle opening/closing:

```
from contextlib import closing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with closing(open('servers_and_paths.csv')) as input,
         closing(open('servers_paths_and_flags.csv', 'wb')) as output:
        func_name(input, output)
```

Comment: Im running 2.4 and am unable to upgrade which is why im not using with statements. wish i could, ive seen many examples using them

Comment: I like the concept of this, I nearly got it working after making it 2.4 compliant and will continue to test it.  Thanks for your input vsekhar